# Notification to open Android Market

Tags: android, google-play, android-notifications

I want to create a [Notification](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html) that, when clicked, opens my application on Android market.

I have tried several things, like below:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(application);
builder.setAutoCancel(true);
// (set titles, icon, ...)

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.android.example"));

builder.setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(application, 0, intent, 0));
Notification notification = builder.build();

NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) application.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
manager.notify(0, notification);
```

However, when clicked, nothing happens. Anyone who knows how to get this to work?

Comment: That looks OK at first glance. Anything interesting show up in LogCat when you tap on it?

Comment: Ehh. It works. I have no idea why it works now. Don't remember having changed anything. Anyways - Thanks for looking at it and checking the quality.

Comment: When I press the back button it does not take me to the activity that started this notification? Any idea how to do it. When I press the back button I just go back to the home screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code posted worked. I might have been having problems with the HTTP version of the market link. Like `http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=<package_name>`.